# TFS: Branching. How to map a branch to IIS for local test

Tags: iis, tfs, testing, localhost, branch

I think there's something I don't understand about Branching

How can I run my website from localhost to test my changes made on a Branch

Let's say my branch structure is

```
-Dev
 -UI
 -App
Main
 -UI
 -App
```

The project UI and App from the main are map in my IIS, it's all working well

Now I want to make some changes in the UI project from Dev branch, and I want to test these changes before I merge them to Main

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I'd actually change things so that your IIS virtual directory is a separate location from your source code.  When you want to test things in IIS then do a build/deploy of either your Main or Dev branches to deploy the app to your new IIS location.

This helps ensure that your deployment is correct and that you haven't missed anything - it'll help prevent "works on my machine" errors.

As an alternative you could always switch to using the VS web server and not worry about configuring IIS at all - but I'm assuming there's reasons for not doing that.